# How to properly call do_QueryInterface with nsCOMPtr

Tags: c++, firefox-addon, xpcom

I'm using Gecko SDK 32.0.2 for win32.
I have this snippet of code, that should work:

```
nsCOMPtr<nsIDOMDocument> doc;
dwi->GetDocument(getter_AddRefs(doc));
nsCOMPtr<nsIDOMDocumentXBL> xbl(do_QueryInterface(doc));
```

But, the compiler says:

```
no instance of overloaded function 'do_QueryInterface' matches argument list nsCOMPtr<nsIDOMDocument>
```

Available overloads are:

```
do_QueryInterface(nsISupports* rawPointer)
```

and

```
do_QueryInterface(already_AddRefed<T>&)
```

How to properly make the function call in this case?

Comment: You might have better luck with this question over at http://ask.mozilla.org they know their mozilla internals big time over there.

Comment: I've posted it to AMO. Thanks...

Comment: AMO is actually http://addons.mozilla.org and http://ask.mozila.org is called ask.m.o for short :) i dont see your post on ask.m.o

Comment: Awaiting moderation. I've just sign up, so probably that's the cause.

Comment: @emirc, if you got an answer at ask.m.o please post it here too.

Comment: I got no answer on ask.m.o., but I found out the cause. It was not related to the message directly, it was due to VSC++ project properties.
Treat WChar_t as Built in Type should be set to "Yes (/Zc:wchar_t)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will self-answer it...
As I've written in the comment, I got no answer on ask.m.o., but I found out the cause. 
It was not related to the message directly, it was due to VSC++ project properties:
Treat WChar_t as Built in Type should be set to "Yes (/Zc:wchar_t)"